# Can someone clear your bank account if they have your name, expiry date, and 16 digit card number but don't have the CVC?

Tags: fraud, debit-card, online

As the title says, I am wondering if someone finds out the details on the front of your card can they commit online fraud with it or is the CVC and OTP providing enough security.

Comment: Please wait at least 24 hours before accepting an answer.  That gives more people time to answer.

Comment: The CVC is required to forge the mag strip on a card, so I'm dubious whether that's a successful vector.  Did an *untrustworthy person* see your card?  (You give it to waitresses all the time -- when not in a pandemic -- so it's not like the numbers are very secret.)

Comment: If you do think you're at risk, regularly log in to the bank's web site to check your balance, and move as much money as possible to an account that's not accessible by the DC.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ronJohn, Someone has seen the details on the front of the card but they definitely don't have the CVC. Should I cancel it or just monitor closely and take the precautions you suggested?

Comment: As mentioned, **that data is not secret**; you willingly give it to someone else **every time you go to a restaurant**.  IMO, you should give a quick glance at your account activity *every night* for "irregular" activity just as a matter of course.

Comment: It's a little different to the restaurant example in that I know that there is an image of the card.

Comment: The waitress can just as easily take an image of your card.  Both sides...

Answer (score 1):

What does a credit card have to do with clearing your bank account?   Credit cards have fraud protection insurance and depending on country and the credit card itself you risk could be close to ZERO.

In the US there is usually a $50 limit to unwarranted use on a card.   It is so little that most card issuers reduce that to $0 because that is just better advertising.

So no your bank account cannot be cleared out.

Really the risk exposure with credit cards is with someone you know.   If someone you know uses your card you are required to file charges against them or run the risk of being on the hook for the whole thing.    The only times I have seen people lose money based on stolen numbers is when a family member uses a card and the person doesn't want to report them.

Debit card rules are below.

[image]

Comment: The question is tagged debit card, not credit card.

Comment: @nanoman - there are just a few changes for debit card (why does anyone use a debit card if they have that much money in the bank!!!!)

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on whether they have other personal details, such as your address.  Not all online merchants ask for the CVC code when placing orders, so a fraudster could place orders with one of them.

But there is a higher chance of you getting the money back from your bank if that happens.  The merchant is taking the risk by not asking for the CVC.

Answer (score 0):

It also depends on how much money you have in the account. If it is $50.00, then probably, but if they are transacting for $5,000.00, then probably not. As @SimonB mentioned, the merchant is balancing fraud risk against ease of transaction, and it doesn’t take much before merchants aren’t willing to take the payment risk and start asking for more credentials. That risk profile also affects the transaction costs with the card systems, so like most transactions, it is a dynamic balance aiming to maximize profit.

Answer (score 0):

The point made in one answer is correct in talking about limitations on your liability against fraud/theft of a debit card.

More to the point is the idea that if you're keeping a close eye on account activity then you should be able to quickly spot problems and notify the bank/credit union, in which case you're then protected against all but potentially the first small amount (varies from institution to institution) of any fraudulent activity.

And one more point...if you have **ANY** reason to suspect that someone has obtained that much info on your card then there should be *NO HESITATION* in contacting the bank and having a new card issued, even if there's no sign of fraud.  Just because nothing happens right away doesn't mean it can't at some point down the road, and it's better to be safe than sorry.